# Maven - extra jars in my war file

Tags: war

My war file is bloating. I have added some dependencies and then removed them. Even though I removed them Maven keeps adding the jars to the war. I am certain that no dependency exists for the jars.

Lets say that I start out a dependency for version 1.0.
I compile and build a war
I change the dependency from version 1.0 to 1.1
I compile and build a war
I decide that this was a mistake and return to version 1.0

Version 1.1 and 1.1 is now included in my war even though nothing is now calling version 1.1 as a dependency.

I have checked the following for using 1.1 as a dependency:
Dependencies I specifically call out.
A dependency on 1.1 by dependency (child dependency?) using Dependency Hieracry
A dependency on the effective pom
My classpath.

Nowhere am I (or my dependencies) asking for version 1.1 but it still gets included in my war.

Some of these not needed dependencies files are invalid. When I deploy the app I get exceptions of type "invalid LOC header (bad signature)".

It is like Maven is not taking out old and no longer needed jars.
How can I keep unneeded jar files from getting packaged in the war?

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean`?

Comment: Yes. I ended up deleting the contents of the /target/[project] folder. It looks like Maven was placing the jars in this folder and then packing the folder contents into the war. Maven was not automatically removing old, unneeded jars.